# unable to open database because of corrupt file

Tags: oracle, datafile, system-tables

when ever i try to open my database i get an error saying

```
SQL> alter database open;
alter database open
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01147: SYSTEM tablespace file 13 is offline
ORA-01110: data file 13: '/oradata/obvs/entry_data02.dbf'


SQL>
```

i dont mind if the data file is deleted as this is my test server i have a production server as well
i think what i can do is transfer all data from prod to test but i have no idea how to do this
however if there is a simple fix for this i can apply would be great

Comment: What version and edition of Oracle?  What OS? What lead up to this occurrence?  There should be clues in the alert log as to exactly what went wrong - especially messages associated with the last shutdown prior to the failed startup, as well as messages associated with the start up itself.  As stated, you can't just copy a data file from another database.  You _could_ use an rman backup of production to perform an rman DUPLICATE DATABASE to _recreate_ your test database.  But I'd rather figure out what went wrong and fix that - as a learning exercise for if/when this happens in production.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create another oracle instance first via **DBCA** or saved DBCA SQL scripts. That process will create SYSTEM tablespace, its data files, as well as the schema user, by default, sys and system. Then you use **imp** or **SQL Loader** utility to load your data to the newly created oracle instance, depending on what format the data was saved before. Your production system tablespace data files cannot be used in your test instance. They have different SCN number.